# Y a-t-il une abréviation qui permet de préciser: "ou dit autrement. blabla", "=. blabla" (autre que "CAD")

Tags: abréviations, incises

La plus proche qui me vient à l'esprit c'est CAD (c'est à dire), mais elle ne va pas dans ce genre de phrase :

> il y a des mots qui ont le même sens (CAD synonymes), et il y en a
>   d'autre qui blabla...

Un autre exemple:

> les sociétés à petite échelle (CAD traditionnelles) sont blabla...

le CAD ne va pas parce que le sens exact du terme entre parenthèses ne devrait pas être "c'est à dire", mais "ou dit autrement".

La distinction est subtile, mais j'ai besoin de précision.

Comment: Peut-être ne justement utiliser aucun mot de liaison : "les sociétés à petite échelle (tradionnelles) sont ..."

Comment: @LaurentS. Effectivement c'est le plus simple, et peut être le mieux dans mon contexte, merci !

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with Sansagent to base an answer on it, but Sansagent Corp. seems to list [**atdt**](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/atdt/fr-fr/) as an abbreviation for  ‘[autrement dit’ and/or ‘en d'autres termes](http://dictionnaire-analogique.sensagent.com/MW791360/ML-fr-fr/).’

Comment: j'ai trouvé ce style sur le web: "les ventes de thé vert ont progressé de 50 % depuis 2012, tandis que celles de "herbal tea", *comprendre les tisanes,* ont augmenté de 31 %"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quant à l'utilisation de l'abréviation [*CAD*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=CAD), on notera qu'on utilise plutôt « c.-à-d. » pour [*c'est-à-dire*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8367565); les traits d'union sont requis, et c'est usuellement en minuscule. Généralement, on [préfère](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3656) aussi l'abréviation *française* à l'abréviation *latine* (*i.e.*).

Si on veut dire que ce qui est entre parenthèses est dit *plus simplement* ou *autrement* comme on explique, je me range derrière l'[idée](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14507/y-a-t-il-une-abr%C3%A9viation-qui-permet-de-pr%C3%A9ciser-ou-dit-autrement-blabla#comment27721_14507) qu'on n'a pas besoin de le préciser; c'est la [nature](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3356) même de la parenthèse qui donne un rôle particulier au terme.

Comment: merci pour ta correction ! Je penche aussi vers cette interprétation.

Answer (score 1):

Vous [pouvez](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/id_est/41434/difficulte) utiliser (i.e. X). Du [latin](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=is) *id est* (littéralement : « ceci est »).

Comment: À noter [cette excellente explication](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie) en anglais et BD qui bien qu'humoristique explique je pense très bien l'emploi de ce terme.

Comment: Mais *i.e.* est juste une transposition directe de *c.-à-d.* en latin (ou l'inverse), ça ne change rien quant à la nuance de sens que recherche Guillaume.

Comment: exact, peut-être "équiv." pour équivalent alors ?

Comment: @SophieMuller Merci Sophie, je saurai maintenant grâce à toi ce que ce i.e, que je vois partout, signifie !